# Inserting a string into the last empty space of another string in Python

Tags: python

I've got two separate strings stored in variable `mystring1` and `mystring2`, I'm looking for a way to take `mystring1` and insert it into the last empty space in `mystring2`

```
mystring1 = 'English French German'
mystring2 = 'Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)'
```

**Desired Output :**
Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet **English French German** Elit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) the second string and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the appropriate tokens back together:

```
t1, t2 = mystring2.rsplit(' ', 1)
' '.join((t1, mystring1, t2))
# 'Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet English French German Elit)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python list insert](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm) function. so your code will be something like that:

```
mystring1 = 'English French German'
mystring2 = 'Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)'

# we will break mystring2 into a list
# insert mystring1 into it as a new element
# convert the list back into a string 

str2_parts = mystring2.split(' ')
# ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', '(Lorem', 'Dolor', 'Amet', 'Elit)']    

index = len(str2_parts) - 1
# 5

str2_parts.insert(index, mystring1)
# ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', '(Lorem', 'Dolor', 'Amet', 'English French German', 'Elit)']


print " ".join(str2_parts)
# Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet English French German Elit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this with this one liner:

```
mystring2.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + mystring1 + " " + mystring2.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rindex()` function returns the last index of a substring. Since python strings are immutable you can not simply index and replace. So forming a new string with the use of slices is the way to go.

```py
mystring2[:mystring2.rindex(' ') + 1] + mystring1 + mystring2[mystring2.rindex(' '):]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Finish this process in one line!**

```
mystring2[::-1].replace(" ", " %s " %mystring2[::-1], 1)[::-1]
```

**Output:** Lorem Ipsum (Lorem Dolor Amet English French German Elit)